# After having installed Navicat 11.1 OS X all the connections are not anymore in their groups

Tags: navicat

I installed Navicat 11.1.4, the first public release, and all my connections are not anymore in their original groups.

Moreover I am not able to move the connections to the original groups.

Answer (score 0):

Support told me they found the problem and will release a fix in the future.

If you have a number of groups you may like the following solution:

1. close Navicat
2. open your **~/Library/Application\ Support/PremiumSoft\ CyberTech/Navicat\ for\ MySQL/Profiles/vgroup.json** with a text editor – I used Brackets but any editor is fine
3. entries will be shown like this one:

   {
     "items": [
       {
         "name": "example.db",
         "type": "CONNECTION"
       }
     ],
     "vgroup_name": "Sample",
     "vgroup_type": "CONNECTION"
   },
4. edit each "items" entry adding the proper server type – like in the follow example:

   {
     "items": [
       {
         "name": "example.db",
         "type": "CONNECTION",
         **"server_type": "MYSQL"**
       }
     ],
     "vgroup_name": "Sample",
     "vgroup_type": "CONNECTION"
   },
5. save the file
6. open Navicat and you will get your connections grouped as in version 11.0 !